# Why are there different ways to restart apache2 and networking in Debian?

Tags: linux, apache, debian

I have two virtual machines with Debian. One I got from school. The other one I made myself.

The way you restart apache2 on the school machine is `service apache2 restart` and they way you restart networking is `service networking restart`.

However, when I tried these commands in the machine I set up myself, I found out that they don't work and that I have to use `systemctl apache2 restart` for apache2 and `systemctl restart networking` for networking instead.

My question is why I have two use two different commands to do the same thing on these machines, even tho they are both running Debian.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question: On the machine, you set up for yourself, you have a newer distribution of Debian than the one from your school. The **service** command was replaced with **systemctl** .

A more detailed answer with differences between these two commands you can find [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/867322/what-is-the-difference-between-service-and-systemctl/867334#867334).

In the older versions, for the same task we used:

*/etc/init.d/{service name} {comand}*

example:

*/etc/init.d/apache2 restart*

Then at a later stage, the **service** command came in.

Now on current distributions, you should use **systemctl** instead of **service**, and it is recomended even on distributions what suport both or all three comands (like ubuntu 20.04 for example).